# How to IP restrict access to a website in IIS8,5 (Windows 2012R2)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have read that to IP-restrict a website in IIS8 to allow only one or more IPs and deny everybody else, you do this:

1. Set "Access for unspecified clients" to "Deny"
2. Add IP-address for "Allow"

(as specified in below screenshot)

However, when I do this (as specified in below screenshot), I am still able to access the site from other IPs.

What is missing here? Is there something else, that needs to be done?

[image]

I tried iisreset and the page is not browser cached on the test-machines, that should not have access.

Comment: When you say test machines, do you mean internal machines? If so could you provide us with the real IP's and the real restriction / allow rules? (or just obfuscate them using the guidelines in [this post](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts))

Comment: That test machines are just PC's that are also internal to the network, and I can see the same IP in the IIS logs, so they are not being NAT'ed, proxied or anything like that.

Comment: These steps should work, make sure the installation of the IP Security is valid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the IP Security under IIS Windows Features is installed you could add this to your web.config to block IP's:

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false"><!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
            <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
            <add ipAddress="192.168.100.1" />
            <add ipAddress="169.254.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
         </ipSecurity>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 4):

After ***a lot of messing about***, I found the following worked for me (IIS 8.5.X on win server 2012 R2)

Ensure Feature enabled for web.config management

- In **IIS**
- Click on the root server
- Double click **Feature Delegation** (under management)
- Scroll down to **IP Address and Domain Restrictions**
- Change to **Read/Write**

(in my case it was Read Only, which was the issue)

Then edit web.config to include

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->            
                <clear />
                <add ipAddress="X.X.X.X" allowed="true" />
                <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" /> 
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Where X.X.X.X is the IP you wish to allow (add a line like this for every IP or IP subnet combo you wish to allow)

**Noteworthy** is the the documentation seems to miss the **allowed="true"** and any mention of the requirement to **allow the feature to be delegated**. Thanks to @Summit for that tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290131/661584)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a proxy between Clients and your IIS Server? You can show in IIS Logs with which IP your Client is coming.

Comment: Good idea, but that was not it. No proxy in between, no. I double-checked in the logs as you suggested.

Comment: Sorry that i can't help you. But i have a similar problem. I have the same rule as you. But my problem is that IIS restrict every IP. Sorry :o|

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around for my situation.

SITUATION:
Need to block IPs on network, but allow IIS access to website for server local applications. Occasional individual and total sub-net access to IIS website.

PROBLEM:
Setting "Edit Feature Settings" to Deny does not work properly. It does not respect the "Allow" list. Nothing, local or network, is allowed to access the hosted website.

WORKAROUND:
Leave "Edit Feature Settings" at "Allow".
Last entry of "Allow/Deny" list is "Deny" to full sub-net.
"Allow" entry for local server IP precedes the sub-net "Deny".
Any individual computers on sub-net to be allowed access have "Allow" entries preceding the "Deny" to full sub-net.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to do file level IP restriction in IIS 7 & above

In IIS manager->In the Content view ,highlight the specific file->Click "Switch to Features view" on Actions pane->In Features View,Double-click "IP Address and Domain restrictions" and then set restriction

I think it works with classic ASP pages as well.